# How should I save two large integer arrays in an SQL table so they relate to eachother

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So I have to save a characters bank to an SQL table in my game. There are two integer arrays that correspond with the bank; playerItems[] and playerItemsN[]. The playerItems array holds the ids for the items in the bank, and playerItemsN holds the amount. Each index in one array corresponds to the same index in the other array.

How would I go about storing these in an SQL table? I was thinking of making an accountBank table with the columns [user][slot][itemID][itemAmt], and just adding a row for each item in the bank. I have a feeling that there would be thousands of rows though as more players get saved.

Can anybody offer some assistance with my problem?

Comment: Rows are not inherently expensive. You do not need to be afraid of rows per se.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed number of items that you'd store in the bank, then I would create two tables. One that would map from user to item id. another table that would store item id and its price. But, again this is useful if you have limited and fixed number of items. Otherwise, the schema that you have defined should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

What DB are you using? Many databases support array based data types. You could create a table with the columns: `[user][slot][itemIdArray][itemAmountArray]`. This schema would be preferable if you only need to query the entire array at once. If you need to query specific items inside the arrays, the more normalized approach you describe in your post would probably be better.